# Hermitian operator in an eigenbasis

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, vectors, eigenvalue

Does "Hermitian operator in an orthonormal eigenbasis" mathematically translate to, $$\sum_{i} \omega_{i} |i\rangle \langle i|$$ Where $\omega_{i}$ is an eigenvalue and $|i\rangle$ is a normalized eigenvector?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "yes". Your statement is correct.