# Hermitian operator in an orthonormal eigenbasis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, vectors, eigenvalue

In [page 36](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.fisica.net/mecanica-quantica/Shankar%2520-%2520Principles%2520of%2520quantum%2520mechanics.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiOtOadh5LbAhXEL48KHVk7A_8QFjABegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw3t59bGXXAPQE5joxcE1CKZ) of Shankar's Principles of Quantum Mechanics is given a theorem:

> *Theorem 10*. To every Hermitian Operator $\Omega$, there exists (at least) a basis consisting of its orthonormal eigenvectors. It is diagonal in this eigenbasis and has its eigenvalues as its diagonal entries.

There is a part of the proof that I do not understand.  Turning to page 36, one reads that, corresponding to the eigenvalue $\omega_{1}$ is a normalized eigenvector $|\omega_{1}\rangle$. Considering $|\omega_{1}\rangle$ to be a basis, $\Omega$ has a matrix form $$\begin{bmatrix}
 \omega_{1}  &  0  &. &. &. & 0\\ 
 0& \omega_{2}& . & . & . &. \\ 
. & . & \omega_{3}&. & . &. \\ 
. &.  &.  &. &.  &. \\ 
. &  .&  .&  .& . &. \\ 
 0& . &.  &  .&  .&\omega_{n}
\end{bmatrix}$$
Where the dots indicate a series of zeroes. This leads me to question. Why does $\Omega$ take that form? Also, why is the first column the image of $|\omega_{1}\rangle$ after $\Omega$ has acted on it?

Comment: We need more context here. Do you know what a hermitian operator is? A basis? An eigenvector? What part of the statement is confusing?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/406803/2451

Comment: @Javier I have edited the post.

Comment: That's quite better, but it would also help if you posted the relevant equations. Not everyone has that book.

Comment: @Javier Sure. I will do that now.

Comment: @Javier I think I have made it clearer.

Answer (score 6):

$\vert\omega_1\rangle$ would not be a basis, but the set $\{\vert\omega_1\rangle,\vert\omega_2\rangle, \ldots,\vert\omega_n\rangle\}$ is a basis.  The eigenvector $\vert\omega_i\rangle$ is such that $\Omega\vert\omega_i\rangle=\omega_i\vert\omega_i\rangle$ so...

With the identification
$$
\vert\omega_1\rangle \to \left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{array}\right)\, ,\quad
\vert\omega_2\rangle \to \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{array}\right)\, ,\ldots \, ,
\vert\omega_n\rangle \to \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\
1 \end{array}\right)
$$
and the matrix representation of $\Omega$ as you suggest you find by simple matrix multiplication that
$$
\Omega \vert \omega_n\rangle = \omega_n\vert\omega_n\rangle
$$
as per the properties of eigenstates of $\Omega$.  Note that under this identification the vectors $\vert\omega_i\rangle$ are an orthonormal basis since $\langle \omega_i\vert\omega_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: @R004 Hermiticity does not depend on the basis if this basis is orthonormal.  $\Omega$ would no longer by diagonal in the new basis but it would still be hermitian.

Comment: one thing to ask. What does "$\Omega$ diagonal in an eigenbasis" mean?

Comment: It means the matrix only has entries on the diagonal, as the matrix in your question.  If your previous comment you allow for the eigenvalues $\omega_1$ to occur twice, so that a linear combination of eigenvectors with this eigenvalue is also an eigenvector.

Comment: please bare with me for a moment. The theorem has in it "To every Hermitian operator" that confuses me. Does "every" speak for all Hermitian operators?

Comment: @R004 Yes every hermitian operator can be brought to diagonal form.  The change of basis that results in the transformation of $\Omega$ to diagonal form is the change of basis that takes the initial basis states to the new basis having the eigenvectors of $\Omega$ as basis states.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\:\mathbb{H}\:$ a n-dimensional Hilbert space and  $\:\Omega\:$ any hermitian operator in it. If  $\:\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{H}\:$ then its image $\:\mathbf{y} \:$ under  $\:\Omega\:$ is
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{y}=\Omega\, \mathbf{x} 
\tag{01}
\end{equation}
This is an equation containing vectors and operators and  is valid independently of the coordinates. Let choose as orthonormal basis the following complete set of mutually orthogonal normalized vectors
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{e}_1\!=\!
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix},
\:\mathbf{e}_2\!=\!
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix},
\cdots\cdots,
\:\mathbf{e}_{n-1}\!=\!
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
\vdots\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix},
\:\mathbf{e}_{n}\!=\!
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{02}
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
(\mathbf{e}_{i})_{j}=\delta_{ij}
\tag{02$^\prime$}
\end{equation}
Then equation (01) is expressed in matrix from
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{y}=
\begin{bmatrix}
y_{1}\\
y_{2}\\
y_{3}\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
y_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \cdots & a_{2n}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & \cdots & a_{3n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & a_{n3} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}\\
x_{3}\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
x_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\Omega\, \mathbf{x} 
\tag{03}
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
y_{i}=a_{ij}x_{j} \qquad \text{(Einstein summation convention)} 
\tag{03$^\prime$}
\end{equation}
Now, suppose we want to express our equations on a different basis say $\:\{\mathbf{u}_{\sigma}\}$, not necessarily orthonormal. To do so , we express the members of the new basis $\:\{\mathbf{u}_{\rho}\}$ in the old basis $\:\{\mathbf{e_{\sigma}}\}\:$
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{u_{\rho}}=s_{\sigma\rho}\mathbf{e_{\sigma}}
\tag{04}
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{x'}=x'_{\rho}\mathbf{u_{\rho}}=x'_{\rho}s_{\sigma\rho} \mathbf{e_{\sigma}}=x_{\sigma}\mathbf{e_{\sigma}} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad x_{\sigma}=s_{\sigma\rho}x'_{\rho}
\tag{05}
\end{equation} 
Then
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{x}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}\\
x_{3}\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
x_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
s_{11} & s_{12} & s_{13} & \cdots & s_{1n}\\
s_{21} & s_{22} & s_{23} & \cdots & s_{2n}\\
s_{31} & s_{32} & s_{33} & \cdots & s_{3n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
s_{n1} & s_{n2} & s_{n3} & \cdots & s_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x'_{1}\\
x'_{2}\\
x'_{3}\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
x'_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
=\mathrm S\, \mathbf{x'}
\tag{06}
\end{equation}
and inversely
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{x'}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x'_{1}\\
x'_{2}\\
x'_{3}\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
x'_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
s_{11} & s_{12} & s_{13} & \cdots & s_{1n}\\
s_{21} & s_{22} & s_{23} & \cdots & s_{2n}\\
s_{31} & s_{32} & s_{33} & \cdots & s_{3n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
s_{n1} & s_{n2} & s_{n3} & \cdots & s_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}^{\boldsymbol{-1}}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}\\
x_{3}\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
x_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
=\mathrm S^{\boldsymbol{-1}}\, \mathbf{x}
\tag{06$^\prime$}
\end{equation}
where $\:\mathrm S\:$  the invertible matrix 
\begin{equation}
\mathrm S\equiv
\begin{bmatrix}
s_{11} & s_{12} & s_{13} & \cdots & s_{1n}\\
s_{21} & s_{22} & s_{23} & \cdots & s_{2n}\\
s_{31} & s_{32} & s_{33} & \cdots & s_{3n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
s_{n1} & s_{n2} & s_{n3} & \cdots & s_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{07}
\end{equation}
Applying $\:\mathrm S^{\boldsymbol{-1}}\:$ on equation (01) we have
\begin{equation}
\mathrm S^{\boldsymbol{-1}}\, \mathbf{y}=\left(\mathrm S^{\boldsymbol{-1}}\,\Omega\,\mathrm S\right)\, \mathrm S^{\boldsymbol{-1}}\,\mathbf{x}  
\tag{08}
\end{equation} 
that is
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{y'}=\Omega'\,\mathbf{x'} \quad \text{where} \quad \mathbf{y'}=\mathrm S^{\boldsymbol{-1}}\, \mathbf{y}  \quad, \quad  \mathbf{x'}=\mathrm S^{\boldsymbol{-1}}\, \mathbf{x}
\tag{09}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\Omega'\equiv\mathrm S^{\boldsymbol{-1}}\,\Omega\,\mathrm S
\tag{10}
\end{equation}
This is the matrix representation of $\:\Omega\:$  in the new basis.

Now, suppose that $\:\Omega\:$ is hermitian. Then it has a complete set of eigenvectors $\:\{\boldsymbol{\omega}_{\sigma}\}\:$ with real eigenvalues $\:\omega_{\sigma}\in \mathbb{R}\:$
\begin{equation}
\Omega\,\boldsymbol{\omega_{\sigma}}=\omega_{\sigma}\,\boldsymbol{\omega_{\sigma}} \qquad \text{(without summation for repeated index } \boldsymbol{\sigma})
\tag{11}
\end{equation}
To express equation (01) with respect to the basis of eigenvectors $\:\{\boldsymbol{\omega}_{\sigma}\}\:$ given that its representation with respect to $\:\mathbf{e_{\rho}}\:$ is (03) let in analogy to (04)
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\omega_{\rho}}=\mathrm w_{\sigma\rho} \mathbf{e_{\sigma}}
\tag{12}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\mathrm W\equiv
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm w_{11} & \mathrm w_{12} & \mathrm w_{13} & \cdots & \mathrm w_{1n}\\
\mathrm w_{21} & \mathrm w_{22} & \mathrm w_{23} & \cdots & \mathrm w_{2n}\\
\mathrm w_{31} & \mathrm w_{32} & \mathrm w_{33} & \cdots & \mathrm w_{3n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\mathrm w_{n1} & \mathrm w_{n2} & \mathrm w_{n3} & \cdots & \mathrm w_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
| & | & | & \cdots & |\\
| & | & | & \cdots & |\\
\boldsymbol{\omega_{1}} & \boldsymbol{\omega_{2}}  & \boldsymbol{\omega_{3}}  & \cdots & \boldsymbol{\omega_{n}} \\
| & | & | & \cdots & |\\
| & | & | & \cdots & |\\
\downarrow & \downarrow  & \downarrow  & \cdots & \downarrow 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{13} 
\end{equation}
This means that the components of the eigenvector  $\:\boldsymbol{\omega_{\sigma}}\:$ with respect to $\:\mathbf{e_{\rho}}\:$ is the $\sigma$-column of the matrix $\:\mathrm W\:$. So
\begin{equation}
\Omega\,\boldsymbol{\omega_{\sigma}}=\omega_{\sigma}\,\boldsymbol{\omega_{\sigma}} \Longrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \cdots & a_{2n}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & \cdots & a_{3n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & a_{n3} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm w_{1\sigma}\\
\mathrm w_{2\sigma}\\
\mathrm w_{3\sigma}\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
\mathrm w_{n\sigma}
\end{bmatrix}
=\omega_{\sigma}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm w_{1\sigma}\\
\mathrm w_{2\sigma}\\
\mathrm w_{3\sigma}\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
\mathrm w_{n\sigma}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega_{\sigma}\mathrm w_{1\sigma}\\
\omega_{\sigma}\mathrm w_{2\sigma}\\
\omega_{\sigma}\mathrm w_{3\sigma}\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
\omega_{\sigma}\mathrm w_{n\sigma}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{14}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{align}
 \Omega\,\mathrm W  & =
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \cdots & a_{2n}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & \cdots & a_{3n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & a_{n3} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm w_{11} & \mathrm w_{12} & \mathrm w_{13} & \cdots & \mathrm w_{1n}\\
\mathrm w_{21} & \mathrm w_{22} & \mathrm w_{23} & \cdots & \mathrm w_{2n}\\
\mathrm w_{31} & \mathrm w_{32} & \mathrm w_{33} & \cdots & \mathrm w_{3n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\mathrm w_{n1} & \mathrm w_{n2} & \mathrm w_{n3} & \cdots & \mathrm w_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
& =
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega_{1}\mathrm w_{11} & \omega_{2}\mathrm w_{12} & \omega_{3}\mathrm w_{13} & \cdots & \omega_{1}\mathrm w_{1n}\\
\omega_{1}\mathrm w_{21} & \omega_{2}\mathrm w_{22} & \omega_{3}\mathrm w_{23} & \cdots & \omega_{2}\mathrm w_{n2}\\
\omega_{1}\mathrm w_{31} & \omega_{2}\mathrm w_{32} & \omega_{3}\mathrm w_{33} & \cdots & \omega_{3}\mathrm w_{n3}\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\omega_{1}\mathrm w_{n1} & \omega_{2}\mathrm w_{n2} & \omega_{3}\mathrm w_{n3} & \cdots & \omega_{n}\mathrm w_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm w_{11} & \mathrm w_{12} & \mathrm w_{13} & \cdots & \mathrm w_{1n}\\
\mathrm w_{21} & \mathrm w_{22} & \mathrm w_{23} & \cdots & \mathrm w_{2n}\\
\mathrm w_{31} & \mathrm w_{32} & \mathrm w_{33} & \cdots & \mathrm w_{3n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\mathrm w_{n1} & \mathrm w_{n2} & \mathrm w_{n3} & \cdots & \mathrm w_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega_{1} & 0  & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & \omega_{2} & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \omega_{3} & \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \omega_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{15}
\end{align}
so
\begin{equation}
\Omega\cdot\mathrm W =  \mathrm W \cdot \mathrm{diag}\{\omega_{1},\omega_{2},\omega_{3},\cdots,\omega_{n}\}
\tag{16}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{diag}\{\omega_{1},\omega_{2},\omega_{3},\cdots,\omega_{n}\}\equiv
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega_{1} & 0  & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & \omega_{2} & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \omega_{3} & \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \omega_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{17}
\end{equation}
and finally
\begin{equation}
\Omega'=\mathrm W ^{\boldsymbol{-1}}\Omega\,\mathrm W= \mathrm{diag}\{\omega_{1},\omega_{2},\omega_{3},\cdots,\omega_{n}\}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega_{1} & 0  & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & \omega_{2} & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \omega_{3} & \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \omega_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{18}
\end{equation}
This diagonal matrix $\:\Omega'\:$ is the matrix representation of the hermitian operator $\:\Omega\:$ with respect to the complete orthonormal basis of its own eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

Hermitian operators are important because their eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal to each other (and can be normalized if required), *and* they form a basis for the Hilbert space on which the operators act.

Take, for instance, the $\sigma_z$ operator. Its eigenvalues are $\pm 1$ and its eigenvectors are $(1,0)^T, (0,1)^T$. You can express *any* vector of the 2-dimensional Hilbert space as a linear combination of these eigenvectors.