# Matrix formulation of the momentum operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra, matrix-elements

For a quantum state $\Psi=c_{1}\psi_{1}+c_{2}\psi_{2}$ with momentum eigenstates $\psi_{1}$ and $\psi_{2}$, the action of the momentum operator $\hat{p}$ is given by
$$\hat{p}\Psi=p_{1}c_{1}\psi_{1}+p_{2}c_{2}\psi_{2}$$
and the matrix form is given by
$$\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12}\\
A_{21} & A_{22}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
c_{1}\\
c_{2}\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
p_{1}c_{1}\\
p_{2}c_{2}\end{pmatrix}$$
However, this would imply that
$$A_{11}c_{1}+A_{12}c_{2}=p_{1}c_{1}$$
$$A_{21}c_{1}+A_{22}c_{2}=p_{2}c_{2}$$
i.e. $A_{11}=p_{1}$,$A_{22}=p_{2}$ and $A_{12}=A_{21}=0$. Does this mean that the momentum operator is a diagonal matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are working in a basis comprised of eigenstates of the momentum operator, it is naturally diagonal in that basis. **any** operator in the basis of its eigenstates would be represented by a diagonal matrix. this is more or less the definition of the basis

Comment: ohh I see. does that mean if the basis is comprised of vectors that are not eigenstates then the matrix would not be diagonal?

Comment: does this also imply that eigenstates always form an orthonormal basis?

Comment: see here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/406861/